# while using event scheduler in mysql it's working only one time

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench6.3.7. I used event scheduler to execute the query everyday morning 9 o'clock I have used the following query

```
delimiter $$
 create event eventtable
 on schedule every '1' day
 starts '2016-11-25 16:00:00'
do 
 begin
<statement>
  end;
  $$;
```

but it's working only one day it's not working daily.What am I missing??.Should i have to execute the query daily? Should I have to on the global scheduler daily? Please help me with this.
Thank you,

Jen

Answer (score 0):

i have created following event for myself,That's working fine.look at this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`developer`@`%` EVENT `event_final_report_horn` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 MINUTE STARTS '2016-09-20 12:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE COMMENT 'Event generates horn final reports after completion of testing' DO BEGIN

if current_Time>='04:00:00' then
    CALL hero_final_report_process_horn_data();
end if;

end
```